# How to implement the change password API in typescript with jwt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, jwt

I created login api and implemented jwt in that. Now I am trying to implement change_password with jwt authentication with cookies or local storage. I tried and not able to do that. Can anybody help me with the change password api and also i attached my Login API.

```
 export let login=async(req:Request,resp:Response)=>{

 var {email , password} = req.body;
 try{

    const user=await User.findOne({email}).lean();

    if(!user){
        return resp.json({message:"user not found"})
    }

    if(await bcryptjs.compare(password,user.password)){
        const token=jwt.sign(
            {
                id:user._id,
                username:user.email
            },config.token.secret)
        
        return resp.json({status:'ok',data:token})
    }

    return resp.json({status:'error',data:'comming soon'})
       
 }catch(error){
     console.log(error);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a different route for change password and there can be multiple ways for doing this. Let keep it simple.

You can ask user the username and existing password and a new password. Check if the existing password matches the password in DB and hash the new password and save it.

```
app.post('/passwordChange', (req, res) => {
     const {username, password, newPassword} = req.body;
     const user = User.findOne({username});
     //check the password matches and then update the User with new password

     const matched = await bcryptjs.compare(password,user.password);
    
     if (matched) {
         User.updateOne({}) // go your things
     }
     else {
        // do tell your to update correct password 
     }
     
})
```

There can be multiple simple and complex ways to achieve it. The above code is a pseudocode, modify to use it in the code.